# xcodebuild - Build Succeeded -> Bus error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bash, xcodebuild

I'm using xcodebuild to compile my project.  I use this on the command line:

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos4.0 -configuration Distribution
```

It returns with the regular build information scrolling by, then shows this:

> ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
>
> Bus error

The package is built fine, so I'm not sure what is causing the Bus error after a successful build.  Normally this wouldn't be a problem and I could ignore it, but the Bus error is killing my automation script.  What is the cause of this bus error?

Another interesting side note, I also get the bus error even if the build fails due to a code sign error.

Edit: I tried putting more RAM in the machine, up to 2GB, in hopes that this would fix the bus error.  It didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xcodebuild](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) is a shell script which must be running a process after the "BUILD SUCCEEDED" message that is faulting and generating the error. The best way to debug shell scripts is to put

```
set -x
```

as the first line of the script which will show the text of commands before the shell executes them.

Comment: I tried this out, I don't get any more information between the two lines.

Comment: Then your culprit is the line marked `+` that is executing last, whatever that might be. I kinda doubt the shell itself is getting SIGBUS.